# How to transform 2D array using values as another array's indices?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D array with indices refering to another array:

```
indexarray = np.array([[0,0,1,1],
                       [1,2,3,0]])
```

The array which these indices refer to is:

```
valuearray = np.array([8,7,6,5])
```

I would like to get an array with the numbers from `valuearray` in the shape of `indexarray`, each item in this array corresponds to the value in `valuearray` with the index on the same location in `indexarray`, ie:

```
targetarray = np.array([[8,8,7,7],
                        [7,6,5,8]])
```

How can I do this without iteration?

---

What I do now to achieve this is:

```
np.apply_along_axis(func1d = lambda row: valuearray[row],axis=0,arr = indexarray)
```

If there is a simpler way, I am interested.

Comment: `targetarray = valuearray[indexarray.flatten()].reshape(indexarray.shape)`

Comment: Feel free to add it is an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to flatten the index array and get the values and reshape it back as follows.

```
targetarray = valuearray[indexarray.flatten()].reshape(indexarray.shape)
```

Comment: Does the simpler `valuearray[indexarray]` work?

Comment: Oh yeah. It works without flattening too :)